# Good alternative to FOP?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm currently using FOP to generate PDF from an XML file.

But I am facing two big issues :

- First: FOP cannot manage OpenType Font files
- Second: fo:float is not implemented yet

So it's impossible for me to produce the PDF I want with FOP.

I need to change FO processor and I would like to know what is the best processor to replace FOP (it has to work on both windows and linux)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had very positive experiences with [Antenna House Formatter](http://www.antennahouse.com/product.htm) for XSL - FO formatting. If you can go with the price tag that is. It supports both [fo:float](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf5fo.htm) and [OpenType](http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf50/font.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first issue. If the license of the Font allows it convert it using
[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) for using in FOP.